# What's the fastest kind of tool for breaking blocks without Efficiency?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Since there is a certain difference between the speed of breaking blocks in Minecraft from the range of tools, which among them is the fastest kind?

Comment: Gold is, in most cases, faster than all others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There are different ways to interpret this depending on the version you're in.

### v.1.16

With a certain test in the anarchy world, it is a cross between netherite and golden tools.

How did I figure it out? Let's get the following tools and blocks.

- Sword -> Cobwebs
- Pickaxe -> Diamond Ores
- Shovel -> Gravel
- Axe -> Logs (any)
- Hoe -> Hay Bales

> Try the test yourself and modify the results in your own plead.

Golden shovels, axes and hoes are much faster, whereas netherite swords and pickaxes are faster.

However, this is somewhat a misleading bit, because blocks break faster depending on the tools and block being broken. For example, anvils are faster to be broken with a golden pick than a netherite one.

### V1.15-

All golden tools with no efficiencies are faster than others.